# Flutter: How to dynamically hide an action in the AppBar?

Tags: flutter

I've got search input as `title` and clear button as `actions` in my AppBar:

```
AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => queryController.clear())],
        title: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          controller: queryController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search...',
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

How can I dynamically display a clear button depending on search field value?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `if (queryController.text.length > 0)` before action you want to hide dynamically and add `setState` to `onChanged` method of the `TextField`, here is your code;

```
AppBar(
  actions: <Widget>[
    if (queryController.text.length > 0)
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () => queryController.clear(),
      )
  ],
  title: TextField(
    autofocus: true,
    controller: queryController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Search...',
    ),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {});
    },

  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the `StatefulWidget` you can use setState and a bool field to track if the action is shown or not:

```
 bool _shouldHideAction;
  TextEditingController _textEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _shouldHideAction = true;
    _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: _shouldHideAction ? [] : [Icon(Icons.clear)],
        title: Text('appbarTitle'),
      ),
      body: TextField(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        controller: _textEditingController,
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          if (newValue.length > 0) {
            setState(() {
              _shouldHideAction = false;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _shouldHideAction = true;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```